# Powershell script calls another script that fails to register a DLL file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

We have an old script to install a program.  There is a bunch of prep work before running the script and we now also have some tasks after the script runs.  I have been able to automate everything with a new script but the original install. Setup.exe and the original script run just fine if called on their own.

Original Script (and this is everything but the signature)

```
start-process "$psscriptroot\Setup.exe" -argumentlist "/verysilent /LocationName=""Test"" (Things like customer and license #) " -wait -NoNewWindow
```

But when I call this script from another script, the program Setup.exe fails to register several dll files.  I think it is a permissions error, but not sure.  I have copied this line exactly into the new script, but it still fails to register the dll file when setup.exe runs.

In the new script, besides copy/paste the old line and also passing in my admin creds, I have also tried :

```
powershell.exe "$PSScriptRoot\oldScript.ps1" -wait
& "$PSScriptRoot\oldScript.ps1"
."$PSScriptRoot\oldScript.ps1"
runas /user:$CurrentUsername ."$PSScriptRoot\oldScript.ps1"
```

I have tried just about anything else I could google or find on this site, but my setup.exe only works correctly if called by me directly or if I run the script to install it directly.  My new script that calls the old one fails.

Current script - Everything up to the setup.exe part, everything after is for other programs and cleanup

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 3.0
Import-Module "\\Module\location\Switch_UAC_Level_Module.psm1" -Force

$CurrentUsername = [Environment]::UserName

#Set UAC level to never notify. Will set correctly at end of install script
Set-UACLevel 0  #Was 1, testing because of permissions issue

$trustpath = "\\location\of\scripts\and\files"

$tempexists = Test-Path $trustpath
if($tempexists -eq $true){    
    Get-ChildItem $trustpath -Recurse -File | % {
       Unblock-File -Path $_.FullName
    }
}

#Set run path to run from script location
if(!(Get-Variable -Name 'PSScriptRoot' -Scope 'Script')) {
    $Script:PSScriptRoot = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
}

."$PSScriptRoot\InstallSetup.ps1" -wait

{ Other install and clean up functions }
```

Because of the location of the install files, an admin user needs to be logged into the PC. No part of this script is running remotely, or shouldn't be.

If it is possible to run setup.exe directly from my current script, that would be awesome.  I'm just not sure why it keeps failing to register the dll file.  Maybe set-strictmode could be an issue in the current one?

Comment: Registering `.dll` files usually requires elevated permissions, i.e 'Run as administrator'.

Comment: The new script runs in an elevated shell already.  And the old script has to run under an admin login, but doesn't elevate.  This only became an issue in the new script, and the only major difference I can see is the new script self-elevates to an admin shell and we use `Set-StrictMode -Version 3.0`.  Can I change the strictmode before this line and put it back after?

Comment: Running with elevated permissions, and running as a user named administrator, or a user who is a member of the administrators group, is not the same thing.

Comment: I gotcha.  But I did also try passing my credentials in the script too.

Comment: I tried just using `-verb runAs` and it failed again, but when I turned set-strictmode back on, it did work.  I think I was loosing my mind and not undoing previous changes.  Thanks!

Comment: Never mind.  I thought it worked, but it was something else.  If the old script works with an admin just running it, how do I pass that ability to a script calling the old script?  I tried to use `-verb runas` at the end of the line, but it still has the dll error